# How to prevent pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sql from adding quotation marks into queries?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a query that I would like to parameterize.
Consider the following simplified example:

```
value_column = "Speed"
my_table = self.spark.read.format("delta").load(file_path)
result = self.spark.sql(
    """
    SELECT DISTINCT
        {my_table}.ReadingTime as time,
        {my_table}.{value_column} as value
    FROM    
        {my_table}
    """,
    value_column=value_column,
    my_table=my_table,
)
```

`value_column` is a string that contains the name of the column I want to return. It can have different values. `spark` is a `SparkSession`

When I run this query I would expect the third line to be translated to `{my_table}.Speed as value`. Instead it adds quotation marks, making it `{my_table}."Speed" as value`. This results in an SQL Syntax error.

Is there any way to prevent this?

The only way I have found is piecing the query together from multiple strings but that really hurts readability.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should be able to build your query as a string - `qryString = "select " + value_column + "from ..."`, and then execute it = `val result = spark.sql(qryString)`.  **But first you need to read up on sql injection.**

Comment: @Andrew that's what I meant when I said I can piece the query together from multiple strings. I just hate how that looks as the real query is much larger and my auto formatter ends a bunch of new lines to it making it super unreadable.